# Bus arrives randomly between 3pm and 330pm. Man goes randomly and only waits 5 minutes

Tags: probability

This question asks for a **geometric solution**.

> A bus arrives randomly between 3pm and 330pm. A man decides he will go randomly to this location between these two times and will wait at most 5 minutes for the bus. After 5 minutes he will take the subway. What is the probability that he will take the subway?

I drew a square on a grid out to 1 on the x and y axis, then drew a diagonal channel through the square that was 1/6 of the time wide and calculated the two triangle areas outside of the channel to be 
$$2\left(\frac12 \frac56 \frac56\right) = \frac{25}{36}$$ chance he would miss the bus but the book, schaums probability and statistics gives the answer at $\frac{61}{72}$.

Is the book answer correct?

Comment: The channel lies fully above the diagonal (if $y$-axis is bus time), so you need to add triangles of unequal size: $\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 (\frac 5 6)^2$.

Comment: If two people are meeting and each is willing to wait $5$ minutes, your procedure would be right.

Comment: yes excellent, do I need to mark it as answered? it is my first question